# Manage registration button in joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

need to delete or add fields in the registration form,Where can i handle this problem in the Joomla?
i Google this question and get some answers about mod_bt_login.php which is in module, but still can not handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/clients-a-communities/communities/210)

It allows you to add custom fields to your registration form and integrates with a lot of other extensions such as Kunena etc.

Do bare in mind that it's quite a heavy extension

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks but i don't need to replace my extension, just need to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Profile plugin allows the addition of supplemental fields in the registration and profile forms of the com_user front end and in the user create/edit form in the back end.

A simple example plugin with the name User - Profile is included in the basic Joomla! installation as a proof of concept. Much more complex plugins are possible.

Ref: http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Example: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-25/user-profile/front-end-form

The solution is good and lightweight, but of you need an easy way of managing these fields I'd recommend Lodder's answer or JomSocial, though both are quite heavy.
It's also good if you need to bundle the plugin with your own extension.